# MATCH with a running lookup_value

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-match

I have data as follows:
[image]

A person can retire when their accumulated corpus is more than required corpus. Hence, for the example shown above, the retirement age will be 55 (i.e., value of E1).

I am having trouble finding the correct formula to locate the column where value in row 2 becomes less than that of row 3.

I tried `=MATCH(B2:G2, B3:G3, 1)` for the "less than" match but no luck. Please help.

Comment: What do you want to "happen" on the sheet when that condition is met?  Conditional formatting?  You're wanting to return one or all of the values?

Comment: No, I have another cell in which I return the retirement age, just like the one in the accepted answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
=INDEX($B$1:$G$1,SUMPRODUCT(MATCH(TRUE,B3:G3>B2:G2,0)))
```

it returns the following, as required:

[image]

---

*What's happening here?* This line (below) is an array formula which creates an array like `{FALSE,FALSE,FALSE,TRUE,TRUE,TRUE}`

```
=B3:G3>B2:G2
```

However, `MATCH` doesn't know how to evaluate the array unless you enter it as an array formula which would usually require entering the formula using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> rather than just  <kbd>Enter</kbd>. A nice trick to avoid having to do this is to wrap the array in a `SUMPRODUCT` formula, so that's the only reason for the `SUMPRODUCT`. The `INDEX` works as normal.

Answer (score 4):

You could also use Aggregate to find the smallest age for which row 3 is greater than row 2

```
=AGGREGATE(15,6,B1:G1/(B3:G3>B2:G2),1)
```

Comment: I was thinking about something using `AGGREGATE`, but opted for a solution with the original `MATCH` function :) +1 for a nice alternative!

Comment: Cheers! +1 for yours obvs.